# Swift use Codable to implement NSCoding

Tags: swift, codable

I'm working with some legacy code that requires my objects to implement NSCoding
I want to take advantage of Codable and get rid of the boilerplate

How can I create a Decoder from Data so that I can initialize my object with it?

```
class Something: NSCoding, Codable {
    public convenience required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        guard let data = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "data") as? Data else { return nil }
        // How to get Decodable
        try? self.init(from: <#T##Decoder#>)
    }

    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self)
        aCoder.encode(data, forKey: "data")
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look promising. `JSONDecoder` uses a fileprivate class called `_JSONDecoder` which conforms to the `Decoder` protocol. See https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift#L802

Comment: Right maybe writing a custom encoder and decoder helps